# MongooseError: Model.findOne() no longer accepts a callback. <beginner>

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I am getting `mongooseError` in the title

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/userDB",{useNewUrlParser:true});

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email:String,
  password:String
});

const secret = "Thisisoursecrets.";
userSchema.plugin(encrypt,{secret:secret,encryptedFields:["password"]});

const User =new mongoose.model("User",userSchema);
```

Please tell me solution.

Comment: Where is the code where you call `findOne` ?

Answer (score 0):

From the [mongoose migrating from 6.x to 7.x guides#dropped-callback-support](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_7.html#dropped-callback-support), methods such as `Model.findOne`

> no longer accept callbacks. They always return promises.

> If you are using the above functions with callbacks, we recommend switching to `async/await`, or promises if async functions don't work for you.